# How to Get SUM() inside GROUP_CONCAT()

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get of all sizes, and making result as one inside `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

- If there are same result inside `GROUP_CONCAT()` then, we can use `SUM()`
- If `NULL` or other size of `product_size.Size_Name` THEN do not get a `SUM()` of this.

By the way this is my query:

```
            SELECT
              product_table.Product_Name,
              SUM(product_quantity.Quantity) AS 'QUANTITY',
              GROUP_CONCAT(
                product_quantity.Quantity,
                ' box/es ',
                product_size.Size_Name,
                ' size' SEPARATOR '\n'
              ) AS 'SIZE'
            FROM
              product_quantity
            RIGHT JOIN
              product_table
            ON
              product_quantity.Product_ID = product_table.Product_ID
            LEFT JOIN
              product_size
            ON
              product_quantity.Size_ID = product_size.size_ID
            GROUP BY
              product_table.Product_Name ASC
```

and so this is the result :

```
  PRODUCT                 QUANTITY                       SIZE

Hawaiian Pizza                 11                   2 - box/es Large size
                                                    3 - box/es Large size
                                                    1 - box/es Small size
                                                    5 - box/es Large size
```

And it is the correct answer on what I trying to get right now :

```
  PRODUCT                    QUANTITY                       SIZE

Hawaiian Pizza                 11                   10 - box/es Large size
                                                    1 - box/es Small size
```

But how ? Any Idea ???

By the way this is my table structure:

For,

table product:

```
        CREATE TABLE `product_table` (
          `Product_ID` int(40) NOT NULL,
          `Product_Name` varchar(400) NOT NULL
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


        INSERT INTO `product_table` (`Product_ID`, `Product_Name`) VALUES
        (1001, 'Hawaiian Pizza'),
        (1002, 'Chicken Alfredo'),
        (1003, 'Chicken Quesadillas'),
        (1004, 'Mexican Pizza'),
        (1006, 'Beef Pepperoni Pizza');

      ALTER TABLE `product_table`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Product_ID`),
      ADD KEY `Product_ID` (`Product_ID`);

      ALTER TABLE `product_table`
       MODIFY `Product_ID` int(40) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,     
       AUTO_INCREMENT=1007;
```

table product_size:

```
        CREATE TABLE `product_size` (
          `Size_ID` int(100) NOT NULL,
          `Size_Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

        INSERT INTO `product_size` (`Size_ID`, `Size_Name`) VALUES
         (1, 'Small'),
         (2, 'Medium'),
         (3, 'Extra Large'),
         (4, 'Large');

       ALTER TABLE `product_size`
       ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Size_ID`);

       ALTER TABLE `product_size`
       MODIFY `Size_ID` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=9;
```

table product_quantity:

```
       CREATE TABLE `product_quantity` (
          `Quantity_ID` int(100) NOT NULL,
          `Quantity` int(100) NOT NULL,
          `Product_ID` int(100) NOT NULL,
          `Size_ID` int(100) NOT NULL
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

        INSERT INTO `product_quantity` (`Quantity_ID`, `Quantity`, 
       `Product_ID`, `Size_ID`) VALUES
        (18, 2, 1002, 3),
        (19, 1, 1001, 2),
        (20, 2, 1003, 1),
        (21, 3, 1002, 2),
        (22, 1, 1002, 3),
        (23, 2, 1003, 3),
        (24, 3, 1004, 4),
        (25, 1, 1003, 3),
        (26, 3, 1006, 3),
        (27, 4, 1002, 3),
        (28, 2, 1004, 4),
        (29, 4, 1002, 3),
        (30, 2, 1002, 3),
        (31, 2, 1002, 2),
        (32, 3, 1003, 3),
        (33, 23, 1002, 4);

        ALTER TABLE `product_quantity`
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Quantity_ID`),
        ADD KEY `Product_ID` (`Product_ID`),
        ADD KEY `Size_ID` (`Size_ID`);

        ALTER TABLE `product_quantity`
        MODIFY `Quantity_ID` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        AUTO_INCREMENT=34;

          ALTER TABLE `product_quantity`
          ADD CONSTRAINT `product_quantity_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY    
          (`Product_ID`) REFERENCES `product_table` (`Product_ID`) 
          ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
          ADD CONSTRAINT `product_quantity_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Size_ID`) 
          REFERENCES `product_size` (`Size_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON
          UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Can you show us the data sample you use to generate that result? And your query doesnt match that result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: As an aside, the second statement here is redundant: `ADD PRIMARY KEY (Product_ID),
      ADD KEY Product_ID (Product_ID);`

Comment: And finish the question

Comment: @Strawberry- No that is `ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Quantity_ID`),
        ADD KEY `Product_ID` (`Product_ID`);` and there is no redundant in my table.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need `group_concat`. a normal `group by` should do it.

```
SELECT product_table.product_name,
       Sum(product_quantity.quantity),
       CONCAT(' box/es ',
              product_size.size_name, 
              ' size') AS 'SIZE' 
FROM   product_quantity 
RIGHT JOIN product_table 
        ON product_quantity.product_id = product_table.product_id 
LEFT JOIN  product_size 
       ON  product_quantity.size_id = product_size.size_id 
GROUP  BY  product_table.product_name ASC,
           product_size.size_name
```

Provide source data and a more precise data output and I can create a sample demo.

Comment: Yes, your answer is nearly correct but what I need to do is a `DISTINCT` of a Product_Name, and `SUM()` of all Quantity. With a single and there is no repeatedly mention of a `Size_Name` on `SIZE` column.

Comment: your question is incomplete, say `result query like this` but not result